# Load a page after successful Google Login

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, google-api

How do you load a new page after you have successfully logged in via the Google api button?

This is what my javascript looks like (given by Google):

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
// Update the app to reflect a signed in user
// Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
window.location.href='main.html'
document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
} else {
// Update the app to reflect a signed out user
// Possible error values:
//   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
//   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
//   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
}
}
```

What am I supposed to fill in to update the app to my homepage, main.html?

Comment: are you using `accounts-google` meteor package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `iron:router`, you can try this.

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
Router.go('/') //or whatever path you want to go
document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
}
```

if you don't have iron:router just add him `Meteor add iron:router`

and first configure the path

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'mainPage'});
```